# Is this use of QMap potentially harmful?

Tags: c++, qt, qmap, qmultimap

```
#include <QMultiMap>

template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
TKey lastKeyOf(const QMap<TKey, TValue>& map)
{
    if (map.isEmpty())
        throw something;
    return (map.end() - 1).key();
}
```

The reason I ask is that:

```
template <typename TKey, typename TValue>
QMultiMap<TKey, TValue>;
```

inherits `QMap<TKey, TValue>` publicly. So if I call:

```
QMultiMap<int, std::string> multimap;
...
lastKeyOf(multimap);
```

All the calls inside `lastKeyOf` get statically bound to their `QMap` versions instead of `QMultiMap` versions, since `QMap` was not intended for polymorphic use (no virtual destructor).

I am not even sure what is this use called. Is it object slicing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should be safe.  QMultiMap just adds a new set of overloaded methods to QMap, you'll only get unexpected results if you use a function inside lastKeyOf() which is overloaded in QMultiMap to have different behavior.  The only overloaded method with a compatible signature and different behavior that I can see is insert().

Having said that, it may make for more straightforward code to avoid QMultiMap and use QMap only with QMap::insertMulti() instead of QMap::insert().

Comment: Thank you! How about the general case? If I declare Base::f() and Derived::f() without virtuality and statically bind an instance of Derived to Base::f() is this considered to be misuse? Is this object slicing?

Comment: This is safe, and it isn't slicing. (Slicing is constructing an instance of Base from a Derived. Here, because the QMultiMap is passed as a reference, nothing is constructed, and it's fine: a QMultiMap "is a" QMap; that's what inheritance means.)